# Decoding a text file in python

Tags: python

What would the syntax look like when decoding a file ,when I try to open the file it shows this #<_io.TextIOWrapper name='DOB.txt' mode='r+' encoding='cp1252'>

Comment: `file = open('DOB.txt', 'r+', encoding='cp1252'); content = file.read(); file.close()`

Comment: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='DOB.txt' mode='r+' encoding='cp1252'>` *is* an open file. What do you intent to *do* with it? Iterate over its lines? Write to it?

Comment: ^^^ that should work. You can also consider `Context Manager` way like - `open('some_file', 'r') as fin: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resulting printout *is* actually your opened file (it's an object).

I suppose you're opening the file like this:

```py
f = open("DOB.txt", "r+", encoding="cp1252")
```

Directly printing `f` will result in your current printed string.

To actually retrieve the contents of your file, you need to call the `read` method.

Example:

```py
f = open("DOB.txt", "r+", encoding="cp1252")
content = f.read()
```

`content` will become the contents of your file as a single string whereas newlines are being encoded by a newline character (depending on your OS either `\r\n` (on Windows) or `\n` on a UNIX-based OS)